# how to change my first view of the map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

i have a map activity in my app.when the user first starts the map activity,the map presents an overview of the europe.i woulk like,when the user fistly starts the map activity to point to greece for example and not the hole europe..is that possible..?thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MapController to do that:

```
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(myLatitude, myLongitude);

MapController controller = map.getController();
controller.setCenter(center);
controller.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL_DEFAULT);
```

or if you want to calculate a zoom that fits some longitude/latitude span:

```
int latitudeSpan = latitude1 - latitude2;
int longitudeSpan = longitude1 - longitude2;
controller.zoomToSpan(latitudeSpan, longitudeSpan);
```

Comment: eclipse highlights red the map.getController and prompts me to create a variable map...what is my wrong?

Comment: map is an instance of MapView. Use the ID of the MapView in your layout XML to create it. I've edited my post above.